How to work around "row is too big" for role definitions without recreating the database?
I am running into the row is too big (ERROR:  54000: row is too big: size 9976, maximum size 8160) error in Postgres related to role permissions on a couple of my instances. I understand that after v12 there was a TOAST table added to help mitigate that issue. I have upgraded the affected instances to v15, but the issue is still occurring.
I have seen many answers about how to structure permissions to avoid this problem, but have not had any luck in finding answers as to how to resolve the problem in a running database. In the email thread where the Postgres developers discussed the implementation of the TOAST tables to address this problem they alluded to manual steps needed to re-init a database to take advantage of the fix, but no reference to the actual steps.
For context, I am running on AWS RDS (not Aurora) and using Vault to generate dynamic database credentials. Because of the error I am unable to drop any permissions or modify existing permissions. I have also been unsuccessful in finding a way to locate the specific row in the pg_catalog that is generating the error.
Can someone please share any steps that they have taken to resolve this situation without having to recreate the entire database? Specifically, being able to drop permissions and users, and/or initialize the missing TOAST tables in the running database. Thank you for your help!

Thanks to the pointers from Laurenz, I was ultimately able to resolve this problem using the following sequence of commands.
Use \x for extended display to show the output in the terminal and then run select string_agg(quote_ident(usename), ',') from pg_catalog.pg_user where usename like '%readonly%';. Copy the full output.
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM <paste the output of above>;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM <paste the output of above>;
DROP OWNED BY <paste the output>;
DROP ROLE <paste the output>;


The problem is that the access control list for the table (column relacl) is part of the pg_class row for the table. That row has to fit into a single table block (8kB), so the row cannot grow any larger than that. If you grant permissions for too many roles on that table, you can get to this impasse.
The only possible solution is to redesign you permission model.  Rather than granting privileges to hundreds of individual roles, use a group system: only the groups get privileges on your tables, and login roles are assigned membership in these roles.

We have changed the permission model, but now we are in a situation where we are unable to remove any entries from that ACL. Until we can remove those entries we are unable to make forward progress. Is it feasible to just issue a DELETE query against that record to reset the state of the database auth and the created roles?

You are unable to REVOKE some of the privileges? That's not what I would expect. Perhaps you'll have to dump the table (without privileges), drop and restore it.

Yes, I am unable to make any permission modifications for some of the database objects. For example:
=> revoke select on table auth_group from "v-aws-conc-readonly-U8JJaOXxb2s1h6kZtTZQ-1688158570";
ERROR:  row is too big: size 9976, maximum size 8160

Try revoking many or all privileges in a single statement. If that doesn't work either, dump/drop/restore is the way to go.
